# YouTube API V3 - Tag limitation

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When attempting to update the details of a video through the API (title, description, privacy and tags) there is a limitation on tags which seems to be far short of the 500 character limit YouTube documentation suggests.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties

Here are two sets of tags which if I add one more character it fails.

> xxx,xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxx xxxxxx,xxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

and

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18119

It feels more like a 100 character limit. (I believe it counts the quotations towards the character limit for how the list is formatted when sent)

Failure is simply that the tag data becomes empty, the rest of the Video details update without error.

I can create more tags in the YouTube video manager, and they will show in my own application when retrieved through the API, but if I simply 'update' through my application the tag data is erased.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162423/youtube-data-api-v3-does-not-support-500-characters-for-tags-property-of-video) if it can help you.

Comment: @KENdi unfortunately not, even with double quotes and spaces etc I am far short of the 500 character limit.

Comment: Same thing, did u fond solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've just counted the number of characters including spacing I'm trying to use for tags - 491, and it's been rejected.